# Proper Connection Method. Not Supported Warnings in Logs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to figure out the correct way to connect to a mongodb within Nodejs using the native driver version 3.10 and the Mongodb Server version of 3.6.5

I've read through documentation that has given different methods and each generate similar warnings.  All of the methods do work, but the warnings that come up with every connection to the database makes debugging query and other code issues more difficult.

my connection code is:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const url = `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_HOST}:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}`
const opts = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    authMechanism: process.env.MONGO_MECH,
    authSource: process.env.MONGO_SRC,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.MONGO_USER,
        password: process.env.MONGO_PWD
    }
}
const Client = new MongoClient(url, opts)
```

this code gives the following messages in the log with every action on the database

```
the options [socketOptions] is not supported
the options [read_preference_tags] is not supported
the options [dbName] is not supported
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [server_options] is not supported
the options [db_options] is not supported
the options [rs_options] is not supported
the options [mongos_options] is not supported
the options [mode] is not supported
the options [tags] is not supported
the options [preference] is not supported
the options [isValid] is not supported
the options [slaveOk] is not supported
the options [equals] is not supported
the options [toJSON] is not supported
```